# Using another R package function without using the whole package as dependency

Tags: r, package

I'm working on an R package here and got this doubt: I need an auxiliar function from another package, but I don't want to include the entire package as a dependency because I only need this one function. What is the correct procedure here? Is it OK if both codes are GPL-2 and I just copy/paste the function to my package? Should I contact the author? Or is it best to include the whole package as a dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's just a small function, I don't see a problem with copying the code into your own package (since everything is GPLed). You should acknowledge the source in your package though.

This has the benefit of insulating your code from any changes in the other package; it's not unusual for updates to packages to break other packages downstream. It has the downside that if those updates were useful (bug fixes or added functionality) then you don't benefit from them either.